# Can't find variable that used in AndroidManifest.xml for android:label

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I would like to rename my application's display name (the name under the app icon on the device app list), but can't figure about  where has been declared the string that used for `android:label`. Unfortunately I just get a project file and can't reach it's developer so I would really appreciate if somebody could help me out where should I search it. As I read in another questions it just a string, but I can't find it in the `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreenActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a string that has been created in your project's `strings.xml` file, located in `res/values/strings.xml` (the name of the actual file is arbitrary, but it is `strings.xml` by default)

Here is the official documentation on String resources: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html

Since you are referencing it in `xml`, you use `@string/app_name`, and it will automatically find the string called `app_name` from your resources

Comment: Thanks Andrew! I knew it gonna be trivial, but not like that.

Comment: hit control + left click to access that String and String location using Android Studio.

Comment: @Mariano Zorrilla great shortcut, I wasn't aware of this but that is super helpful

Answer (score 1):

The string can be found in the `strings.xml` file, which is located inside the `res/values` directory.